# Paypal success return URL redirects to 404 page

Tags: paypal, opencart

When i have integrated the Opencart with PayPal, i have configured the return Url correctly as below,

```
$this->data['return'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout&payment=success');
```

But when the paypal redirects the page the url seems like below,

```
checkout%252fcheckout&payment=success
```

It seems Slash will be encoded to '%252f'.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Which paypal extension or method are you using?  Are you writing this from scratch or modifying core components? Typically the return url should be `$this->data['return'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');`

Comment: I am using paypal standard and Yes, i have modified the core component, due to my requirement.

Comment: I doubt this will make a difference but here's something to try: change the link arguments to way they are normally formatted which would be `$this->url->link('checkout/checkout', 'payment=success', '');` or if you want ssl use `$this->url->link('checkout/checkout', 'payment=success', 'SSL');`